# Where is Address Book in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, contacts

After I upgrade to Mountain Lion from Snow Leopard, I can no longer find "Address Book" in the application but only "Contact".

The application "Contact" does not allow me to add or remove groupings of contacts. Where is the good old address book?

Comment: The ability to add groups is under the file drop down menu, as far as remove groupings not sure. When selecting the group to be removed what happens when you use the edit menu and select delete?

Comment: Highlight entry and press delete, shift for all the entries seems to work (+ turn of sync in iCloud and all other accounts)

Comment: This doesn't remove the group as such but merely the content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the new Contacts Application for Mountain Lion there are no buttons for group management, only menu items.

Under the File Menu, there are `New Group`, `New Group from Selection`, and `New Smart Group…` menu items.

When you have a group selected, under the Edit menu there will be a `Delete Group` menu item available.

To be able to select groups, you need to be in the proper view under the View menu: `Groups`.